# Gitlab-ci Kubernetes cluster doesn't create namespace (job failed : namespace not found)

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have en error when I run my gitlab-ci pipeline.

> Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: setting up credentials: namespaces "ci-3ebcf582" not found.

The pipeline is running in a kubernetes cluster. I am trying to configure my runner to create a namespace for each pipeline to isolate them.

My gitlab-runner values.yml is as follows:

```
rbac:
  create: true
  clusterWideAccess: true

runners:
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      [runners.kubernetes]
        image = "ubuntu:20.04"
        namespace_overwrite_allowed = "ci-.*"
```

Anyone have an idea to unlock me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`namespace_overwrite_allowed` is not overwriting namespaces, but it is validation that namespace will be overwritten, anyways you have to check that your kubernetes cluster is connected in gitlab, so it will be able to manipulate resources in cluster (f.e. create namespaces)

Also if it is already connected, you may try reconnect it

Link to GL configuration variable -> https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html